# How to update QStandartItemModel without freezing the main UI

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I'm starting to learn PyQt4 and have been stuck on something for a long time now and can't figure it out myself:

Here is the concept: There is a TreeView with custom QStandartItemModel, which gets rebuild every couple of seconds, and can have a lot (hundreds at least) of entries, there also will be additional delegates for the different columns etc. It's fairly complex and the building time for even plain model, without delegates, goes up to .3 sec, which makes the TreeView to freeze.

Please advice me for the best approach on solving this. I was thinking of somehow building the model in different thread, and eventually sending it to the TreeView, where it would just perform setModel() with the new one, but couldn't make that work.

here is some code that may illustrate the problem a bit:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, os, re, time

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
REFRESH = 1

class Reloader_Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.loaders = ['\\', '--', '|', '/', '--']
        self.emit(SIGNAL('refresh'))
    def run(self):
        format = '|%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S| '
        while True:
            self.emit(SIGNAL('refresh'))
            self.sleep(REFRESH)

class Model(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, viewer=None):
        QStandardItemModel.__init__(self,None)
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        stTime = time.clock()
        newRows = []
        for r in range(1000):
            row = []
            for c in range(12):
                item = QStandardItem('%s %02d%02d' % (time.strftime('%H"%M\'%S'), r,c))
                row.append(item)
            newRows.append(row)
        eTime = time.clock() - stTime
        outStr = 'Build %03f' % eTime
        format = '|%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S| '
        stTime = time.clock()
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(),  0, self.rowCount())
        self.removeRows(0, self.rowCount())
        self.endRemoveRows()
        eTime = time.clock() - stTime
        outStr += ', Remove %03f' % eTime
        stTime = time.clock()
        numNew = len(newRows)
        for r in range(numNew):
            self.appendRow(newRows[r])
        eTime = time.clock() - stTime
        outStr += ', Set %03f' % eTime
        self.emit(SIGNAL('status'), outStr)
        self.reset()

w = QWidget()
w.setGeometry(200,200,800,600)
hb = QVBoxLayout(w)
tv = QTreeView()
tvm = Model(tv)
tv.setModel(tvm)

sb = QStatusBar()
reloader = Reloader_Thread()
tvm.connect(tvm, SIGNAL('status'), sb.showMessage)
reloader.connect(reloader, SIGNAL('refresh'), tvm.build)
reloader.start()

hb.addWidget(tv)
hb.addWidget(sb)
w.show()
app.setStyle('plastique')
app.processEvents(QEventLoop.AllEvents)
app.aboutToQuit.connect(reloader.quit)
app.exec_()
```

---

Thanks for the tips.
Here is the situation I've gotten so far:
Each refresh I build a new model and send it to the TreeView... it's fast, but I dunno what is happening with the current model of the TreeView and how to deal with it, also it seems the memory used by my 'app' is constantly increasing.

Another thing is I want to retain my selection, but based on item data, rather than visual rectangle or row order, so I've done that too, but it looks too dirty/hacky to be the proper way. Any help on this will also be appreciated. Code follows:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, os, re, time

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
REFRESH = 1

class Reloader_Thread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.moveToThread(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            model = Model()
            #model.connect(model, SIGNAL('status'), self.emitStat)
            if model.build():
                self.emit(SIGNAL('refresh'), model)
            self.sleep(REFRESH)

    def emitStat(self, stat):
        self.emit(SIGNAL('status'), stat)

class Tree(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

    def resetModel(self, model):
        stTime = time.clock()
        # gather old selection
        oldSel = set()
        currModel = self.model()
        for index in self.selectedIndexes():
            id = currModel.itemFromIndex(index).data().toString()
            oldSel.add('%s'%id)
        # setup new
        self.setModel(model)
        selModel = self.selectionModel()
        for r in range(model.rowCount()):
            item = model.item(r,0)
            rowId = '%s' % item.data().toString()
            if rowId in oldSel:
                sel = QItemSelection(model.index(r,0), model.index(r,model.columnCount()-1))
                selModel.select(sel, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
        self.setSelectionModel(selModel)
        self.emit(SIGNAL('status'), 'TV setModel: %03fs' % (time.clock() - stTime))

class Model(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, viewer=None):
        QStandardItemModel.__init__(self,None)

    def build(self):
        stTime = time.clock()
        newRows = []
        for r in range(1000):
            row = []
            var = QVariant('%d'%r)
            for c in range(12):
                item = QStandardItem('%s r%02dc%02d' % (time.strftime('%H"%M\'%S'), r,c))
                item.setData(var)
                row.append(item)
            newRows.append(row)
        eTime = time.clock() - stTime
        outStr = 'Build %03f' % eTime
        format = '|%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S| '
        stTime = time.clock()
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(),  0, self.rowCount())
        self.removeRows(0, self.rowCount())
        self.endRemoveRows()
        eTime = time.clock() - stTime
        outStr += ', Remove %03f' % eTime
        stTime = time.clock()
        numNew = len(newRows)
        for r in range(numNew):
            self.appendRow(newRows[r])
        eTime = time.clock() - stTime
        outStr += ', Set %03f' % eTime
        self.emit(SIGNAL('status'), outStr)
        #self.reset()
        return True

w = QWidget()
w.setGeometry(200,200,800,600)
hb = QVBoxLayout(w)
tv = Tree()

sb = QStatusBar()
reloader = Reloader_Thread()
tv.connect(tv, SIGNAL('status'), sb.showMessage)
reloader.connect(reloader, SIGNAL('refresh'), tv.resetModel)
reloader.connect(reloader, SIGNAL('status'), sb.showMessage)
reloader.start()

hb.addWidget(tv)
hb.addWidget(sb)
w.show()
app.setStyle('plastique')
app.processEvents(QEventLoop.AllEvents)
app.aboutToQuit.connect(reloader.quit)
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.

You need a separate worker thread to recompute the model for you (as often as you want, time based or signal based). Then you need to hook up a signal when the computation is done to notify the main thread.

There are a few gotchas you have to be aware of.

1. QObjects live in threads. Signal/slot paradigm (at least in C++ QT) by default works locally to the owner thread. If you want to send a signal cross thread you need to specify it explicitely (see signal/connect documentation).
2. In order to work with the model in a worker thread you need to "move" the model into the worker thread (there should be a method called movetothread or something like that).
3. Ensure the main thread and the worker thread are properly synchronized.

QT also has QFuture (not sure if PyQT has it) which can be used to hold the new model in the main thread and automatically reload it when the worker thread regenerates it.

Good luck.